# Checking if random variables are independent, finding Var and Cov

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with distributions $N(6,7), N(4,5)$ respectively. Let $Z:=3X+5Y$, then:

$1.$ random variables $X, Z$ are independent

$2.\ Cov(X,Z)=24$

$3.\ VarZ=188$

I have to prove or disprove these.

I know that $X\sim N(6,7)$, $Y\sim N(4,5)$ and $X+Y\sim N(10,12)$, so is it true that $3X\sim N(18,21)$, $5Y\sim N(20,25)$ and then $3X+5Y\sim N(38,46)$? If so what should I do next and how can I calculate EZ? Lets assume, I know that when $X\sim N(m,\sigma^2),$ then $EX=m$ and $VarX=\sigma^2$.

Comment: $VarZ=Var(3X+5Y)=9VarX+25VarY=9*7+25*5=188$, I've skipped the covariance because $X,Y$ are independent. Am I right?

Comment: Moving on: $Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,3X+5Y)=3Cov(X,X)+5Cov(X,Y)=3Cov(X,X)=3VarX=3*7=21 \neq 24$ 

is it right too?
And how should I check if $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo. I mean how to check if $X$ and $Z$ are independent

Comment: You showed that the covariance between $X,Z$ is non-zero.

Comment: Okay, but without calculating the covariance, can I show in any other way that $X,Z$ are dependent?

Comment: You can use the definition - if they are independent then their joint PDF $f_{x,y}$ can be decomposed as $f_x \cdot f_y$. However, proving dependency in your case is quite easy as $Z$ is a non-trivial function of $X$.